# how to change version number of an App from iTunesConnect with state Prepare for Submission

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I accidentally created a new version of an App in iTunesConnect with wrong version number. It is in state `Prepare for Submission`. So,I want to change the version number. Is there any possibilities to do that? or Is it possible to remove the app? so,i can create a new version.

Comment: The accepted answer should be changed

Comment: @gunas please change accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979607/5218685

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can update the version name in  a **version** field in the **General App Information** area.
Screenshot is as below

[image]

Comment: He is asking about version number in iTunes connect.

Comment: @DidatsTriadi yes, there is a version field for you to update the version number in new iTunes connect.

Comment: i have a release that is pending, how do i change that app version? I tried cancelling the release, but the version stayed the same.

Comment: Do I need to submit ipa again for updated itunes connected version ? I mean if I added 3.11.2 and it is in status as "Prepare for Submission" and I have uploaded build for 3.11.2 it is working and it is in Test flight--- now at some later point my team decides  lets have 3.12 without 3.11.2. How this should be handled ?

Comment: @Anand you can just update the version field in itunnesconnect to 3.11.2

Comment: I have to update version from 3.11.2 to 3.12. I have already uploaded binary for 3.11.2. Now if I change my version in iTunes connect to 3.12 , then I need to update new binary .. right ? Since old binary is pointing to 3.11.2

Comment: @Anand, you can just update version field to 3.12 without uploading new binary.

Comment: How about the bundle version ? It will still be pointing to 3.11.2 ..right ? If I change version in iTunes connect general app section to 3.12 then my bundle IPA should also point to 3.12 ..right ? In such case I need to upload new IPA with 3.12

Comment: @Anand bundle number won't affect the version number displayed in app store

Comment: Which version number gets parsed from the App Store receipt? The version number submitted in the IPA? Or the version number entered under General App Information?

Comment: @otto the version number entered under General App Information will be displayed in App Store

Answer (score 28):

I have the same problem before.

My solution:

1. Submit the IPA first, status will be changed to "Waiting for Review";
2. Press the red button "Reject the binary" in iTunes Connect, status will be changed to "Developer Rejected";
3. Restart the process again.

---

**UPDATE** As of 2015, iTunes Connect has updated, allowing users to change version number without uploading any binary.

Comment: will it delete the binary alone or the entire version?

Comment: Binary alone. The information will be unlocked for edit (I tried it last year, not sure it has changed or not; its layout has changed a lot, I know)

Comment: if it deletes the binary alone then what is the purpose of deleting it? I just need to change the version number not the binary..

Comment: As in your case, the version is locked & cannot be edited. Rejecting the binary unlocks the edit mode

Comment: sorry,I misunderstood your previous comment.Thank you so much.It works.

Comment: with new itunesconnect it is possible to edit version number without submitting any build. just edit it in the General App Information at the bottom of your new version in the Versions section

Comment: Just change the version from General tab as stated by others

Answer (score 18):

Go to iTunes --> App store --> iOS App at left side --> Prepare for submission --> General App Information --> Version

[image]

Comment: Do I need to submit ipa again for updated itunes connected version ? I mean if I added 3.11.2 and it is in status as "Prepare for Submission" and I have uploaded build for 3.11.2 it is working and it is in Test flight--- now at some later point my team decides lets have 3.12 without 3.11.2. How this should be handled ?

Comment: @Anand,,,Of course you're out of this issue now but in order to make sure I think no need for that, I mean the version on iTunes is not conditional to build versions, please corrective am wrong.