# iOS: AppStore wrong version entered, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, app-store

My Application on AppStore was released with version **1.1**
I clicked **New Version** where 
I unfortunately, added version **1.0.2** instead of **1.2**

Now after Archive was made , i uploaded the binary, it came an error.

How can i revert that version to **1.2** instead of **1.0.2**

Comment: The answers on this question may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649319/how-to-change-version-number-of-an-app-from-itunesconnect-with-state-prepare-for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649319/how-to-change-version-number-of-an-app-from-itunesconnect-with-state-prepare-for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change version number of an App from iTunesConnect with state Prepare for Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649319/how-to-change-version-number-of-an-app-from-itunesconnect-with-state-prepare-for)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version number must be the same in the binary aswell as in itunes connect so the solution is to change either one.

**To change it in itunes connect**
1. login to your itunes connect account 
2. myApps 
3. click on the app in question
4. scroll down to general app information
5. make changes
[image]

**To change it in itunes connect**

In your project navigator, click on your app name.
[image] it should be the first thing below this image.

Then you can make your changes on the following page [image]

Comment: this is old answer. now there not such option under the general information menu in 2024. so please update the answer. or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the version and save on iTunes connect. Which is available below app icon in general details section of your app on iTunes Connect